# Python Openpyxl writing date to excel as short date

Tags: python, excel, date, openpyxl

I am trying to write dates to an excel file using Openpyxl.  I am using the following lines to write the date.

```
dttm = datetime.datetime.strptime(ls25Dict[cell.value][2], "%m/%d/%Y" )   
ws1['B'+ str(cell.row)].value = dttm
```

This writes the date to excel but in the wrong format.  This is the output:

2018-01-09 0:00:00

I am trying to get it to be 1/9/2018.  Basically change the format to Short Date in excel.

Anyone know how to change it before the date is written to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you **always** have to provide your own format for dates and times, because these are stored as serials. openpyxl defaults to ISO formats for minimal ambiguity.

Comment: So I will just have to change the date in excel after the file is created?

Comment: No, set the number format of the cell to the style you want.

Comment: Thank you, I found it. http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html?highlight=number%20format

Comment: Fixing broken link: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#number-formats